# Godot: does parse_json accept multiple JSON objects?

Tags: godot, json

If I had a JSON file that had multiple objects, can the method read through without some form of exception?

Comment: Have you considered trying it?

Comment: As Tyyppi_77 says, this is something you can answer much faster for yourself by just making a multi-object JSON file and trying to parse it. Does the data come through as expected? Or does it throw an Exception? Boom, you have your answer - no internet hearsay required. :)

Comment: @DMGregory Alright, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [the implementation of `parse_json`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/7ae4cb7f7dc9913f6b1c7e9c9ff90a481ce93ba7/modules/gdscript/gdscript_functions.cpp#L1145) calls `JSON::parse`. [`JSON::parse` looks like](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/b16c309f82c77d606472c3c721a1857e323a09e7/core/io/json.cpp#L461) a fairly generic JSON parsing routine, but it does expect the top-level of the JSON fed to it to be a single value (since defers, once, to `_parse_value`).

Thus, it looks like you can provide it JSON containing multiple objects within a top-level array or structure. But if you provide it a string that happens to contain two independent sets of JSON, it will only parse the first one.